# Why does it not allowed to use try-catch statement without {}?

Tags: c#

Why can't I use code like this ?

## 1

```
int i = 0;

try i = int.Parse("qwerty");
catch throw;
```

## 2

```
try i = int.Parse("qwerty");
catch;
finally Log.Write("error");
```

And should write like this

## 1

```
int i = 0;

try { i = int.Parse("qwerty"); } catch { throw; }
```

## 2

```
try { i = int.Parse("qwerty");}
catch {}
finally {Log.Write("error");}
```

PS:

I can use if-else statement without {}. Why should I use them with try-catch(-finally) statement ? Is there any meaningful reason ?

Is it only because that some people think that code is hard to read ?

Several months ago I asked that question on russian programming forum but I got no satisfactory answer ...

Comment: While we on the subject a try turnery would be nice like you have in if eg ( x > 5 ? "Big" : "Small") .  I know programming for exceptions has its issues but could make a lot of views etc much simpler.

Comment: Try, ternary is what he means. Where ? is the ternary operator in C#. Matt, that would be interesting but I could see it going horribly awry.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's what the language designers decided.

In either case, even a single line `if` is dangerous - people add lines expecting them to be included in the `if`, which of course, as they are not in `{}`, they are not.

Comment: You are so right. I've fallen pray to thinking a statement is included in a one line if. It's not worth the time it saves.

Comment: A few months ago I got tired of wasting precious whitespace and brain cycles on preconditions like `if (arg == null) { throw ArgumentNullException("arg"); }`.  So far the world has not come to an end.  But I suppose I agree in the general case. :)

Comment: I agree: `if()` with no `{}` should NOT be allowed IMO, especially in C/C++ where the thing after the if() may be a `#DEFINE` that disappears (seen that happen: a debug statement after an if() which disappeared when compiling the release build).

Comment: I agree that remove the {} in any case should be allowed. What can you save, a few line but you pay back with a bigger probability of making mistake. many IDEs I know will auto include the {} for you by default like : Netbeans, Eclipse, XCode

Comment: @Oded, I don't like curly braces in some situations. Some People always use {} with a single-line if-statement ( if(x>6){ DoSomeAction();} ). Some people don't use them ( if(x>6) DoSomeAction(); ). I know that some programmers forget about {} when they use several instructions inside of if. I read that it is a very common mistake. I have never done such mistakes (Did i write last sentence right ?).

Nevertheless, it seems that there is no important reason for use {} every time i need try-catch statement...

Comment: @alex - _you_ may never make the mistake. How about the next programmer? And the one after that?

Comment: @Oded, a word "next" associates with a popular mtv show but it's offtopic. So the final answer is "language designers decided". I marked your answer as useful.

Answer (score 2):

C# probably made the braces a requirement because C++ did.  My guess as to why they're required in C++ is that it makes it easier to write nested and multiple catch blocks without making mistakes.  The braces add an extra level of scope, which can be convenient, but I can't think of a reason why it would be *required*.

Answer (score -1):

Honestly, I'm not sure why, but I asked myself that same question a few years ago.  Only answer that I can think of that makes any sense is that the `try` must open and end with a bracket and `catch` must have something in there to catch within brackets, because it's not a normal if... else... statement, but rather they are like `functions`.

Comment: What if I don't want to handle an exception ? int GetValue(string s){ int i = 0; /*default value*/ try i = int.Parse(s); catch; finally return i;}